Proof that if $R \ne 0$ - commutative Artinian ring then $R \cong R_1 \times \ldots \times R_n$
I'm trying to proof the following proposition. If $R \ne 0$ - commutative Artinian ring then $R \cong R_1 \times \ldots \times R_n$, where each $R_i$ is local Artian.
We known that fact, if $R$ is Artian then $R / J(R)$ is semisimple, where $J(R)$ - Jacobson radical of $R$. Also if $R$ is Artian then $J(R)$ is nilpotent. Hence $R$ -- a semiperfect ring. By Muller theorem $R$ contains a full orthogonal set of local idempotents $e_i$ ($i = 1, \ldots n$, $e_i^2 = e_i, 1 = e_1 + \ldots + e_n, e_i e_j = e_j e_i = 0, e_i R e_i$ - a local ring). If $e_i R e_i$ is local then $\bar e_i \bar R$ - a minimal right ideal of $\bar R = R / J(R)$. How to obtain from this that $R \cong R_1 \times \ldots \times R_n$, where each $R_i$ is local Artian?
